# Set system focuse to a particular component after an action event

Tags: java, swing, setfocus

I want when :

`comboBox.getSelectedIndex() == 1`

Then system focus should set to my `textField1` .

this is my code:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == comboBox) {
        if (comboBox.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {

            // set focus to textField1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
component.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Comment: What is different between `requestFocus()` and `requestFocusInWindow()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `textField1.requestFocus();`

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == comboBox) {
        if (comboBox.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {

            // set focus to textField1
            textField1.requestFocus();
        }
    }
}
```